# Could not decrypt a base64String using CryptoSwift

Tags: ios, swift, encryption, aes, cryptoswift

String for encryption "secret"

after encryption      "64c2VjcmV0"

this is the code that works properly

```
    let inputNSData: NSData = input.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
    let inputBytes: [UInt8] = inputNSData.arrayOfBytes()
    let key: [UInt8] = self.generateArray("secret0key000000") //16
    let iv: [UInt8] = self.generateArray("0000000000000000")  //16
    do {
        let encrypted: [UInt8] = try AES(key: key, iv: iv, blockMode: .CBC).encrypt(inputBytes, padding: PKCS7())    
        let decrypted: [UInt8] = try AES(key: key, iv: iv, blockMode: .CBC).decrypt(encrypted, padding: PKCS7())   
        let decryptNsData: NSData = NSData(bytes: decrypted, length: decrypted.count)     
        let c = decryptNsData.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions.Encoding64CharacterLineLength)
        let decryptedString: String = NSString(data: decryptNsData, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) as! String
        print("String after decryption\t\(decryptedString)")
    } catch {
        // some error
    }
```

but i could not decrypt by using the same key and iv
I am getting fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value for the encrypted string

```
    let key: [UInt8] = self.generateArray("secret0key000000") //16
    let iv: [UInt8] = self.generateArray("0000000000000000")  //16
    let input: String = "64c2VjcmV0"

    var encryptedStrData = NSData(base64EncodedString: input, options: NSDataBase64DecodingOptions())!
    let inputBytes: [UInt8] = encryptedStrData.arrayOfBytes()
    print("String in uint8\(inputBytes)")
    //var keyData = keyStr.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false)!
    //var ivData:NSData = ivStr.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false)!
    do{
    let decryptedTryData = try AES(key: key, iv: iv, blockMode: .CBC).decrypt(inputBytes)
        print(decryptedTryData)
    }
    catch{

    }
```

I am getting fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value for the encrypted string

Comment: The length of a Base64 string should be divisible by 4. Your input 64bXVkaXRjbmU= is 14 char long .. and is thuse not a valid base64 string

Comment: Thank you @Ebbe M. Pedersen for the concern.....i gor what you are suggesting but could you tell me what is wrong in the code that has resulted in improper base64 strings

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using Base64 when it is not necessary, only Base64 encode non string data.

Here is the first test code:

```
let inputBytes: [UInt8] = Array("secret".utf8)
let key:        [UInt8] = Array("secret0key000000".utf8) //16
let iv:         [UInt8] = Array("0000000000000000".utf8)  //16

var encryptedBase64 = ""
do {
    let encrypted: [UInt8] = try AES(key: key, iv: iv, blockMode: .CBC).encrypt(inputBytes, padding: PKCS7())
    let encryptedNSData = NSData(bytes: encrypted, length: encrypted.count)
    encryptedBase64 = encryptedNSData.base64EncodedStringWithOptions([])

    let decrypted: [UInt8] = try AES(key: key, iv: iv, blockMode: .CBC).decrypt(encrypted, padding: PKCS7())
    let result = String(bytes: decrypted, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
    print("result\t\(result )")
} catch {
    // some error
}
print("encryptedBase64: \(encryptedBase64)")
```

Output:

> result: secret
>   encryptedBase64: 0OCxa0yJszq9MvkrWjn3wg==

```
let encryptedData = NSData(base64EncodedString: encryptedBase64, options:[])!
print("decodedData: \(encryptedData)")
let encrypted = Array(UnsafeBufferPointer(start: UnsafePointer<UInt8>(encryptedData.bytes), count: encryptedData.length))

do {
    let decryptedData = try AES(key: key, iv: iv, blockMode: .CBC).decrypt(encrypted)
    let decryptedString = String(bytes: decryptedData, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
    print("decryptedString: \(decryptedString)")

}
catch{
    // some error
}
```

Output:

> decryptedString: secret

Notes:

Don't use CryptoSwift, it does not use the build-in encryption hardware and is **400 to 1000 times slower** than the Apple Security.framework Common Crypto. It is also not well vetted and used non-certified encryption code.

Don't use a string directly as the key, it is not secure. Instead derive a key from the string using PBKDK2 (Password Based Key Derivation Function).

Comment: @zaph I want to provide key as this [Int8] = [2,-56,8]. Is this possible?

Comment: UnsafePointer compiler error swift5: "No exact matches in call to initializer"

Answer (score 0):

Base64 strings must be divisible by 4. Yours is not.
You can use a website, such as https://www.base64decode.org, to test your strings.

Comment: Thank you @Морт for the concern.....i gor what you are suggesting but could you tell me what is wrong in the code that has resulted in improper base64 strings

Answer (score 0):

For Swift3 (to avoid the UnsafePointer error) this has worked for me for the second part (decoding the base64 variable):

```
let encryptedData = NSData(base64Encoded: encryptedBase64, options:[])!
print("decodedData: \(encryptedData)")

let count = encryptedData.length / MemoryLayout<UInt8>.size

// create an array of Uint8
var encrypted = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: count)
// copy bytes into array
encryptedData.getBytes(&encrypted, length:count * MemoryLayout<UInt8>.size)

do {
    let decryptedData = try AES(key: key, iv: iv, blockMode: .CBC).decrypt(encrypted)
    let decryptedString = String(bytes: decryptedData, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)!
    print("decryptedString: \(decryptedString)")

}
catch{
    // some error
}
```

Comment: can you please tell me what you pass as "iv"

Comment: iv should be the same that you entered during encryption ,  it must be 16 bits. e.g -  let iv:         [UInt8] = Array("0000000000000000".utf8)